# C# facebook SDK dont work

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website write (.net 4) and i am tring to create some facebook login.

After i download Facebook sdk for c#, i am tring to get user info using the access token.

It seems to me that i am doing something wrong, all the examples i examined, were little bit diffrent from mine. instead of getting me paramethers by :

```
me["id"] // mine

me.id // examples
```

when i try to get values like the examples i got errors.

also i am having problem with get the email address of user, already add email to scope:

This method responsible for get the access token:

```
public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                strAppId, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, strScope, Request["code"].ToString(), strAppSecret);

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }

            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            return access_token;
        }
```

This method responsible for get user information:

```
  public string GetUserInfo(string strToken)

         {
             var client = new FacebookClient(strToken);
             dynamic me = client.Get("me");

             User user = new User();
             try
             {

                 string user_id = me["id"];
                 string user_first_name = me["first_name"];
                 string user_last_name = me["last_name"];
                 string user_name = me["username"];
                 string user_location = me["location"]["name"];
                 string user_city = me["hometown"]["name"];
                 //user_mail = me.email;                 }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {

             }


             return string.Empty;

         }
```

when try to run on me.email or me["email"] i get this error:

```
'me.email' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'   dynamic {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook`. It's easy to use and has all these properties already done.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app